# Java Error when i press button

Tags: java, applet

[image: Error Snap]

1. I try to fill string arabic word from Jtextfiled1
2. press button search
3. display the result in jtextfield2

but you can see the list off errors in red

Please help, following is my code

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

         ArabicStemmer Stemmer=new ArabicStemmer();
         String ArabicWord=   jTextField1.getText().toString();
         jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(Stemmer.stemWord(ArabicWord)));

    }
```

errors in red :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: javaapplication1.ArabicStemmer
    at javaapplication1.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:146)
    at javaapplication1.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:13)
    at javaapplication1.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:45)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Please paste here stacktrace. It's not possible to read it from the screenshot.

Comment: the error changed to  C:\Users\Malek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\src\javaapplication1\NewJFrame.java:146: error: cannot access ArabicStemmer
          ArabicStemmer Stemmer=new ArabicStemmer();
  bad source file: C:\Users\Malek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\src\javaapplication1\ArabicStemmer.java
    file does not contain class javaapplication1.ArabicStemmer
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error